# Reduce complexity, increase maintainability of multiple If-Else statements?

Tags: c#, if-statement, maintainability

I have a method that I am trying to reduce the complexity and increase the maintainability. It contains multiple `if`-`else` statements, all setting different information as below:

```
ClassOne varOne = null;
if (condition == null)
{
    varOne = mammal;
}
else
{
    varOne = reptile;
}


ClassTwo varTwo = null;
if (diffCondition == null)
{
    varTwo = dog;
}
else
{
    varTwo = cat;
}
```

I have a lot more that 2 statements, above is an example. Is there a way of reducing the complexity of this one method?

Comment: [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)?

Comment: If the conditions are always in the form `if(x == null) ... else`, you could use the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) `?`. For example, `ClassOne varOne = condition == null ? mammal : reptile;`.

Comment: If they are always binary a ternary may be fine, otherwise perhaps a `Dictionary` would be in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [ternary `?:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) operator:

```
ClassOne varOne = condition == null ? mammal : reptile;
ClassTwo varTwo = diffCondition == null ? dog : cat;
```